# How do I "enableEdgeToEdge" in an activity using Jetpack Compose, but only for the status bar and not the navigation bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What I WANT is to make only the status bar translucent at the top, but retain the normal behavior of the navigation bar at the bottom. How can I accomplish this?

So technically I do not want to "enableEdgeToEdge", I want to enable top edge to navigation bar.

Currently I have this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

which effectively makes the status bar and navigation bar translucent.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you.
Scaffold(
modifier = modifier.navigationBarsPadding(),
this is the example of how can you give padding for navigationBar